# Twilio <Gather> enhanced attribute

Tags: timeout, twilio

I used  widget in my project to receive the person answers on a phone call and based on the respond it proceeds to the next step. The responds are limited to 'yes' and 'no'.
I noticed most of the time, the 'timeout' situation happens in  step which prevents the flow to go to the next step which is 'split based on'. It means it does not receive the answer no matter how the person says the word. I looked for the possible solution and I came across the premium speech model by adding the enhanced attribute. I'm not sure know if it is the solution or there is a better way to overcome this issue. any suggestion in this matter would be much appreciated since I couldn't find anything helpful through my google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Studio, place the Text to speech in the Gather Input on Call Widget rather than a Say Widget, that will accomplish what @jack has mentioned in Studio (allow you to barge into the conversation for speech or DTMF collection). Studio doesn't currently support Enhanced Gather.

You can look at the Studio Execution logs, to see what the Gather Widget received as Input (SpeechResult) or the Split Based on Widget, to see what it received and what it is comparing to based on your logic. Sometimes, Yes or No may end in a period for example, but you are looking for Yes or No (.)

[Widget Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library)

[Understanding Twilio Studio Flow](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/08/15/understanding-twilio-studio-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

make sure `<Say>` or `<Play>` are nested in the  tag like this

```
<Response>
<Gather>
<Say>Please say Yes Or No</Say>
</Gather>
</Response>
```

not like this

```
<Response>
<Gather>
</Gather>
<Say>Please say Yes Or No</Say>
</Response>
```

If you can share some images or code, it would be helpful.

Comment: thank you @jack , I'm quite new in twilio, I made the project in studio and I only found the JSON file, where can I check these tags?

Comment: Oh these tags would be  in a TwiML Bin, but your using Studio, which if your new is user friendly and powerful. Check the "SPEECH RECOGNITION LANGUAGE" field, make sure you chose the right language. additionally you there's a field to put in hints. Also as Alan answered type the instructions to the caller in the Gather widget itself.

Comment: thank you @jack, the result was better than before. maybe in next step I'm gonna try working with TwiML.